# Rails - Client side validation issue in multi step form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, client-side-validation

I have a form in rails which is a multi step form 
i have used this gem
`'client_side_validations', github: "DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations", branch: "4-2-stable"`

and the form is

```
    <%= form_for @employee, :html => {:multipart => true, :id => 'msform'}, :validate => true do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :target => @employee %>
      <ul id='progressbar'>
        <li class='active'>Account</li>
        <li>Address</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
      <!-- fieldsets -->
      <fieldset>
        <h2 class='fs-title margin_0 bg_red white-text left-align margin_B20'>Create
          Account</h2>

        <div class='row form_row padding_L20 padding_R20 margin_B15'>
          <div class='col s12 m4 left-align'>
            <label for='usrname' class='form_label'>User Name</label>
          </div>
          <%= f.fields_for :profile do |p| %>
            <div class='col s12 m8'>
              <div class='input-field'>
                <%= p.text_field :name, :validate => true, :class => 'validate form_input' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class='row form_row padding_L20 padding_R20 margin_B15'>
          <div class='col s12 m4 left-align'>
            <label class='form_label'>Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class='col s12 m8'>
            <div class='input-field'>
              <%= f.text_field :email, :validate => true, :class => 'validate form_input' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='row form_row padding_L20 padding_R20 margin_B15'>
          <div class='col s12 m4 left-align'>
            <label class='form_label'>Role</label>
          </div>
          <div class='col s12 m8'>
            <div class='input-field'>
              <%= f.select :role, Employee.roles.keys, :selected => @employee[:role],
                           :class => 'browser-default' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

          <div class='row form_row padding_L20 padding_R20 margin_B15'>
            <%= f.fields_for :contact do |c| %>
              <div class='col s12 m4 left-align'>
                <label for='phno' class='form_label'>Phone Number</label>
              </div>
              <div class='col s12 m8'>
                <div class='input-field'>
                  <%= c.text_field :phone_no, :class => 'validate form_input' %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type='button' id="next_form" name='next' class='next action-button' value='Next'/>
        <% end %>

 </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class='fs-title margin_0 bg_red white-text left-align margin_B20'>Create
      Address</h2>

    <h3 class='fs-subtitle left-align margin_0'>Current Address</h3>
    <%= f.fields_for :contact, :validate => true do |c| %>
      <div class='row form_row padding_L20 padding_R20 margin_B15'>
        <div class='col s12 m4 left-align'>
          <label class='form_label'>Address 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class='col s12 m8'>
          <div class='input-field'>
            <%= c.text_field :current_address1, :class => 'validate form_input',
                             :id=> 'current-address-1', :validate => true %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row form_row padding_L20 padding_R20 margin_B15'>
        <div class='col s12 m4 left-align'>
          <label class='form_label'>Address 2</label>
        </div>
        <div class='col s12 m8'>
          <div class='input-field'>
            <%= c.text_field :current_address2, :class => 'validate form_input',
                             :id=> 'current-address-2' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='row form_row padding_L20 padding_R20 margin_B15'>
        <div class='col s12 m12 left-align'>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='input-field col s12 m6'>
              <%= c.country_select :country, {prompt: 'Please select a country'}, {:class => 'browser-default'}, {:validate => true} %>
            </div>

            <div class='input-field col s12 m6'>
              <%= render partial: 'subregion_select', locals: {parent_region: c.object.country} %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='row form_row padding_L20 padding_R20 margin_B15'>
        <div class='col s12 m12 left-align'>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='input-field col s12 m6'>
              <%= c.text_field :city, :class => 'validate form_input', :placeholder =>'City',
                               :id=>'curr-city', :validate => true %>
            </div>
            <div class='input-field col s12 m6'>
              <%= c.text_field :zip, :class => 'validate form_input', :placeholder =>'Zip Code',
                               :id=>'curr-zip', :validate => true %>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

the form id is #msform and the next button id is #next_form so now i have followed the client side validation in multistep form and i put the javascript code as

```
$("#next_form").bind("click", function(e) {
    //If the form is valid then go to next else don't
    var valid = true;
    // this will cycle through all visible inputs and attempt to validate all of them.
    // if validations fail 'valid' is set to false
    $('[data-validate] input:visible').each(function() {
        var settings = window.ClientSideValidations.forms[this.form.id]
        if (!$(this).isValid(settings.validators)) {
            valid = false
        }
    });
    if(valid){
        //code to go to next step
        $("#msform").enableClientSideValidations();
    }
    // if any of the inputs are invalid we want to disrupt the click event
    return valid;
});
```

I am getting error messages in the first form but when i click the next and the other step form comes in the client side validation doesn't work 
i am unable to solve this since 3 days please help !!

Comment: Can you please expand upon "it doesn't work"? what do you actually observe? What do you expect to see instead? What have you tried to revolve the issue yourself?

Comment: Have you tried starting with a cut-down version of the form (with say just one input) and checking that works... then adding in a second input etc... and seeing what works and what breaks in this very simple version? If you get that working, then you can add the inputs one by one until it's all working.

Comment: yes i tried with one input and enabled the validation like this $("#current-address-1").enableClientSideValidations();
but this doesn't work

Comment: ...and what was the result? what did you see? what did you expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that validator is bugging because you are using 'this' variable on button event. Try using specific form selector like this:

```
var form = $('#msform');
var form_validators = ClientSideValidations.forms[form.attr('id')].validators
if (!form.isValid(form_validators)) {
  valid = false;
}
```

Also try reseting the validator after showing the form:

```
if(valid){
  $("#msform").resetClientSideValidations();
  $("#msform").enableClientSideValidations();
}
```